# API to change touchpad 'Cursor speed' in Win10 dynamically without restarting

Tags: c#, c++, windows

We need to reduce Win10 touchpad cursor speed certain state in our application. So, i was planning that when the application enter a specific state, we will change touchpad cursor speed at run time by using some Windows API. And when coming out of the specific state, revert the touchpad cursor speed to original value.

However, i did not find any Windows API to change touchpad 'Cursor speed' dynamically without restarting. I found API to change mouse speed (SystemParametersInfo). But this API only changes the mouse cursor speed. It does not  change touchpad cursor speed.

I tried changing the below registry. But the problem with changing registry is that touchpad cursor speed gets updated only after system restart. I need an API to change touchpad cursor speed without restarting system (similar to how we can change mouse speed using SystemParametersInfo)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\CursorSpeed

Any suggestions in this regard will be really very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 11, build 26027, the user's touchpad settings can be queried and modified dynamically via the SystemParametersInfo API. For example:

```
// Get the user's touchpad settings.
TOUCHPAD_PARAMETERS params = {};
params.versionNumber = TOUCHPAD_PARAMETERS_LATEST_VERSION;
RETURN_IF_WIN32_BOOL_FALSE(
    ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETTOUCHPADPARAMETERS, sizeof(params), &params, 0 /*fWinIni*/));

// Override the touchpad's right-click zone to have a 50% width and 33% height.
// NOTE: changing user settings should only be performed in response to explicit user intent.
params.rightClickZoneWidth = 50;
params.rightClickZoneHeight = 33;

RETURN_IF_WIN32_BOOL_FALSE(
    ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETTOUCHPADPARAMETERS, sizeof(params), &params, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE));
```

More details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-tuning-guidelines